# Ajax and PHP same page not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a JSON object via ajax to the same page. While running my code, the ajax function does seem to send the data, as I can see on the response, that the $id in the PHP code, is changed to 200, but I am unable to display it on the webpage. I have included the jquery.js file (I'm not sure if I need to add another js library or not).
I tried looking at a lot of stackoverflow answers but was unable to solve my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

PHP Code:

```
   <?php
        if(isset($_POST['area_id'])){
            $id = $_POST['area_id'];
            echo "Area ID: ".$id;
        } else {
            echo "test";
        }
    ?>
```

JQuery AJAX

```
var dat = {area_id: 200, title: 'title'};
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data: dat,
    success:function(res){
        alert(res);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is shown in the `alert()`?

Comment: I get an HTML response where I can see "Area ID: 200"

Comment: So then... how is this not working?  Do you expect `echo "Area ID: ".$id;` to produce something *other than* `"Area ID: 200"`?

Comment: It does not output on the HTML page. Should it not print on the HTML page as well?

Comment: All you're doing with the response is `alert(res);`.  An alert just displays the string in a message box.  It doesn't alter the page in any way.

Comment: I meant with the PHP code, where it echoes the Area ID. Does that only come to the response and not update the HTML page in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[based on comments to the question...]

Your page isn't being updated because you've written no code to update it.  `echo` simply emits text to the output, and `alert()` simply displays text to the user in a message box.  In order to update the page client-side you'll need to write code which does that.

For example, if you have an element with `id="output"` and want to set the response text to that element, you'd do this:

```
$('#output').text(res);
```

That element would then get that text:

```
<div id="output">Area ID: 200</div>
```

Server-side code has no way of altering a page that's already been sent to the browser.  When your client-side code receives new data via AJAX, that client-side code needs to use that data in whatever way you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `alert(res);` with your display code. For example, suppose you want to display the ajax response in a div in the HTML:

```
<div id="display-div"></div>
```

then the javascript you need is

```
$('#display-div').html(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sending AJAX request to the same page, you should `exit()` your PHP script:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['area_id'])){
        exit("Area ID: " . trim($_POST['area_id']));
    }
    echo "test";
?>
```

This way, you're ensured that nothing else is printed out in a response. Otherwise the entire HTML page (including scripts) will be sent back.

---

Then you can inject your response into DOM using [@David's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34732970/962734) example.